# Creating a macro calculator - getting a NaN result when trying to add a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

The calculator was working fine until I added the activity level from the drop down. Depending on the users selection for activity level, the value returned should be multiplied by the corresponding value associated with each activity level. I have added the values that it should be multiplying the result by. However, it doesn't seem to be seeing the 'activityLevel' variable inside the function. Am I not declaring this properly? When I try to run the code, it returns a NaN result.

```js
/* Calculate female macros */
(function() {
  function calculateFemale(femaleWeight, femaleHeight, femaleAge) {
    femaleWeight = parseFloat(femaleWeight);
    femaleHeight = parseFloat(femaleHeight);
    femaleAge = parseFloat(femaleAge);
    activityLevel = (activityLevel);
    return (((femaleWeight * 4.3) + (femaleHeight * 4.7) - (femaleAge * 4.7)  * activityLevel);
  }

  var womanBMR = document.getElementById("womanBMR");
  if (womanBMR) {
    womanBMR.onsubmit = function() {
      this.result.value = calculateFemale(this.femaleWeight.value, this.femaleHeight.value, this.femaleAge.value, this.activityLevel.value);
      return false;
    };
  }
}());


/* Calculate male macros */
(function() {
  function calculateMale(maleWeight, maleHeight, maleAge) {
    maleWeight = parseFloat(maleWeight);
    maleHeight = parseFloat(maleHeight);
    maleAge = parseFloat(maleAge);
    activityLevel = (activityLevel);
    return (((maleWeight * 6.3) + (maleHeight * 12.9) - (maleAge * 6.8) + 66) * activityLevel);
  }

  var maleBMR = document.getElementById("manBMR");
  if (manBMR) {
    manBMR.onsubmit = function() {
      this.result.value = calculateMale(this.maleWeight.value, this.maleHeight.value, this.maleAge.value, this.activityLevel.value);
      return false;
    };
  }
}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.w-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  background-color: #3898EC;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.w-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 940px;
}
.w-row:before,
.w-row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.w-row:after {
  clear: both;
}
.w-col {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.w-col .w-col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.w-col-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.w-col-2 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #f70909;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.text-block {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.text-block-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.text-block-4 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.list {
  padding-left: 140px;
}
.div-block {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.paragraph {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #020202;
}
.column-1 {
  background-color: #f0e8e8;
}
.image {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="w-row">
  <div class="w-col w-col-1"><img src="images/apple.jpg" alt="apple"></div>
  <div class="column-1 w-col w-col-2">
    <h1>Healthy Eating</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-container">
  <h2>Calculator</h2>
</div>

<div class="w-container">
<div><em>Use the form below if you are female.</em></div>
  <form id="womanBMR">
    <fieldset>

      <p>
        <label for="femaleWeight">Weight (lbs)</label>
        <input id="femaleWeight" name="femaleWeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="femaleHeight">Height (inches)</label>
        <input id="femaleHeight" name="femaleHeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="femaleAge">Ages (years)</label>
        <input id="femaleAge" name="femaleAge" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
    <select id = "selActivity">
      <option value = "1.2">Sedentary</option>
      <option value = "1.375">Light Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.55">Moderate Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.725">Very Active</option>
      <option value = "1.9">Extra Active</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="result">Base Calories Per Day</label>
        <input id="result" name="result" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="w-container">
<div><em>Use the form below if you are male.</em></div>
  <form id="manBMR">
    <fieldset>

      <p>
        <label for="maleWeight">Weight (lbs)</label>
        <input id="maleWeight" name="maleWeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="maleHeight">Height (inches)</label>
        <input id="maleHeight" name="maleHeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="maleAge">Ages (years)</label>
        <input id="maleAge" name="maleAge" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
    <select id = "activityLevel">
      <option value = "1.2">Sedentary</option>
      <option value = "1.375">Light Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.55">Moderate Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.725">Very Active</option>
      <option value = "1.9">Extra Active</option>
        </select>
      </p>      
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="result">Base Calories Per Day</label>
        <input id="result" name="result" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="js/calculatorscript.js"></script>
<a href="home.html" class="button w-button">Home</a><a href="recipes.html" class="button w-button">Recipes</a><a href="recipes.html" class="button w-button">Tips</a><a href="faq.html" class="button w-button">FAQ</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the parameter to the function definition and to call `parseFloat`

```js
/* Calculate female macros */
(function() {
  function calculateFemale(femaleWeight, femaleHeight, femaleAge) {
    femaleWeight = parseFloat(femaleWeight);
    femaleHeight = parseFloat(femaleHeight);
    femaleAge = parseFloat(femaleAge);
    return ((femaleWeight * 4.3) + (femaleHeight * 4.7) - (femaleAge * 4.7)  + 655);
  }

  var womanBMR = document.getElementById("womanBMR");
  if (womanBMR) {
    womanBMR.onsubmit = function() {
      this.result.value = calculateFemale(this.femaleWeight.value, this.femaleHeight.value, this.femaleAge.value);
      return false;
    };
  }
}());


/* Calculate male macros */
//*This function calculates the macros for a male, it requires three variables be input
//*by the user. Their weight, height, and age. It then returns the 
(function() {
  function calculateMale(maleWeight, maleHeight, maleAge, activityLevel) {
    maleWeight = parseFloat(maleWeight);
    maleHeight = parseFloat(maleHeight);
    maleAge = parseFloat(maleAge);
    activityLevel = parseFloat(activityLevel);
    return (((maleWeight * 6.3) + (maleHeight * 12.9) - (maleAge * 6.8) + 66) * activityLevel);
  }

  var maleBMR = document.getElementById("manBMR");
  if (manBMR) {
    manBMR.onsubmit = function() {
      this.result.value = calculateMale(this.maleWeight.value, this.maleHeight.value, this.maleAge.value, this.activityLevel.value);
      return false;
    };
  }
}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.w-button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  background-color: #3898EC;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.w-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 940px;
}
.w-row:before,
.w-row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.w-row:after {
  clear: both;
}
.w-col {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.w-col .w-col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.w-col-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}
.w-col-2 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #f70909;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.text-block {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
.text-block-3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.text-block-4 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.list {
  padding-left: 140px;
}
.div-block {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.paragraph {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #020202;
}
.column-1 {
  background-color: #f0e8e8;
}
.image {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="w-row">
  <div class="w-col w-col-1"><img src="images/apple.jpg" alt="apple"></div>
  <div class="column-1 w-col w-col-2">
    <h1>Healthy Eating</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-container">
  <h2>Calculator</h2>
</div>

<div class="w-container">
<div><em>Use the form below if you are female.</em></div>
  <form id="womanBMR">
    <fieldset>

      <p>
        <label for="femaleWeight">Weight (lbs)</label>
        <input id="femaleWeight" name="femaleWeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="femaleHeight">Height (inches)</label>
        <input id="femaleHeight" name="femaleHeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="femaleAge">Ages (years)</label>
        <input id="femaleAge" name="femaleAge" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
    <select id = "selActivity">
      <option value = "1.2">Sedentary</option>
      <option value = "1.375">Light Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.55">Moderate Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.725">Very Active</option>
      <option value = "1.9">Extra Active</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="result">Base Calories Per Day</label>
        <input id="result" name="result" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="w-container">
<div><em>Use the form below if you are male.</em></div>
  <form id="manBMR">
    <fieldset>

      <p>
        <label for="maleWeight">Weight (lbs)</label>
        <input id="maleWeight" name="maleWeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="maleHeight">Height (inches)</label>
        <input id="maleHeight" name="maleHeight" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="maleAge">Ages (years)</label>
        <input id="maleAge" name="maleAge" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
    <select id = "activityLevel">
      <option value = "1.2">Sedentary</option>
      <option value = "1.375">Light Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.55">Moderate Activity</option>
      <option value = "1.725">Very Active</option>
      <option value = "1.9">Extra Active</option>
        </select>
      </p>      
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="result">Base Calories Per Day</label>
        <input id="result" name="result" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="js/calculatorscript.js"></script>
<a href="home.html" class="button w-button">Home</a><a href="recipes.html" class="button w-button">Recipes</a><a href="recipes.html" class="button w-button">Tips</a><a href="faq.html" class="button w-button">FAQ</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only added the drop down menu to the male calculator function where i did define the drop down menu. I have changed the code so that the variable is defined in both the male and female calculators.